# Why does a sum of a series belong to Calculus?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

When I use Microsoft Mathematics I see the sum of a series belonging to Calculus inside of the calculator pad. Can someone explain, why does the sum of a series belong to Calculus?

Comment: Limits of partial sums. Nice theorems demonstrating relation to integrals.

Comment: Categorization is arbitrary.  I first learned infinite sums from an algebra book, no differential calculus was involved.  Either way, there is no part of mathematics where one theorem is true but in another area it isn't.

Comment: First of all, I believe the term ''sum of a series" is rarely seen in any formal text. ''Series'' is just ***series*** itself (talking a sum of a series sounds very weird), which is defined to be the limit of the sequence of partial sums. Since the keyword ***limit*** is involved, it of course belong to calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series is defined to be a sum...sums are used extensively in calculus...

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it @NorbertWillhelm

Comment: There was no better answer, indeed.